# How to migrate a project built on Spring Boot 2.0.4 from mysql5 to mysql8?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Our project needs to be migrated from mysql5 to mysql8. In our project we use Spring Boot 2.0.4. I couldn't find any information about MySql8 configuration in the official Spring documentation.

I've done the following steps till now:

1. Added spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect in properties file.
2. Added mysql-connector-java version 8.0.17 as a dependency.

Are these steps enough to complete migration or should I do anything else?

Comment: can you share the steps you have taken to upgrade the tasks?

Answer (score 0):

If your `spring.datasource` configurations are working, changing the hibernate dialect to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` should work too. Also make sure you are using a Hibernate version in which the MySQL bundle is available.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```